# Cube detection using C++ and openCV

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, shapes, edge-detection

I am currently working on a robotic project: a robot must grab an cube using a Kinect camera that process cube detection and calculate coordinates.

I am new in computer vision. I first worked on static image of square in order to get a basic understanding. Using C++ and openCV, I managed to get the corners (and their x y pixel coordinates) of the square using smoothing (remove noise), edge detection (canny function), lines detection (Hough transform) and lines intersection (mathematical calculation) on an simplified picture (uniform background).

By adjusting some threshold I can achieve corners detection assuming that I have only one square and no line feature in the background.

Now is my question: do you have any direction/recommendation/advice/literature about cube recognition algorithm ?

What I have found so far involves shape detection combined with texture detection and/or learning sequence. Moreover, in their applications, they often use GPU/parallellisation computing, which I don't have...

The Kinect also provided a depth camera which gives distance of the pixel from the camera. Maybe I can use this to bypass "complicated" image processing ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: using the depth image is imho the best idea. Try to find planes in the 3D space. If there are some intersecting planes whch have similar size, it's probably a cube. Using 2D image only gives some problems like perspective distortion etc which makes it ambiguous whether the object is a cube or just looks like a cube from a special perspective (unless you use multiple images from different positions)

Answer (score 1):

OpenCV 3.0 with contrib includes surface_matching module.

> Cameras and similar devices with the capability of sensation of 3D
>   structure are becoming more common. Thus, using depth and intensity
>   information for matching 3D objects (or parts) are of crucial
>   importance for computer vision. Applications range from industrial
>   control to guiding everyday actions for visually impaired people. The
>   task in recognition and pose estimation in range images aims to
>   identify and localize a queried 3D free-form object by matching it to
>   the acquired database.

http://docs.opencv.org/3.0.0/d9/d25/group__surface__matching.html